# Deploy designer.war on Weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic, drools, jbpm

When deploying `designer.war` (for DRools) to WebLogic 12c, the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: [HTTP:101249][ServletContext@2539776[app:designer module:designer.war path:null sp
ec-version:3.0]]: Servlet class org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet for servlet DirectoryListingServlet could not be
loaded because the requested class was not found in the classpath .
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:577)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704)
>
```

Can advise the correct deployment steps for `designer.war` on Weblogic 12c?

Comment: Is the catalina jar part of your war file or in your weblogic classpath? You can add it to the startWeblogic.sh script if you need to

Comment: I tried adding the catalina jar to the lib folder(see console log below):      <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <The following extensions directory contents added to t
he end of the classpath:
C:\Weblogic\domains\base_domain\lib\catalina-6.0.32.jar.>.    However, I still get the same error.

Comment: As stated in its website, there is different versions of this war file for `Apache` and `JBoss` application servers. Which version are you trying to use? Have you made any changes in war file to make it compatible with `WebLogic`?